# How to prevent re-ordering of views while dragging in android?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-view

I am working on a small application which will allow me to drag a view and drop over another view in order to get them swapped. ItemTouchHelper (utility class) provides me this functionality, but, it re-orders the positions of the views inside the layout.

For example, using ItemTouchHelper class, if I want to drag view at position 1 to position 3, then, views at position 2 & position 3 will shift their positions in order to make the space for view which is being dragged.

What I have tried? 
--> Using drag shadow builder! But, drag shadow builder doesn't allow you to hold, drag and move the entire view from it's position. Instead, it drags the shadow and performs the swap.

Is there any way, where, we can only swap the views using Item Touch Helper class without re-ordering of the views?

Comment: of course you want to swap `RecyclerView`s items?

Comment: yeah! Recycler view items! But, when I used item touch helper class, items re-ordered their positions. Hence, I created 4 simple views (buttons) and used drag shadow builder. I got the swap, though I couldn't get the swap movement we get using item touch helper class!

Comment: what are you doing in `Callback#onMove`?

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onItemMove(int firstPosition, int secondPosition) {
     Collections.swap(mItems,firstPosition,secondPosition);
        notifyItemMoved(firstPosition,secondPosition);
        return true;
    }

Comment: onItemMove? what is it? i mean what are you doing in `ItemTouchHelper.Callback#onMove`?

Comment: I misinterpreted brother. Pardon me! This is I think you wanted to look! ?                                                                                               @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder source, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        if (source.getItemViewType() != target.getItemViewType()) {
            return false;
        }

        // Notify the adapter of the move
        mAdapter.onItemMove(source.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    }

Comment: and is `onItemMove` called at all?

Comment: Yes. onItemMove is called inside onMove!